# Intellij code style setting for wrapping on multi line function arguments

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

The Spark code style requires four character indentation for multi parameter methods.  So: the following code -as presently formatted by IJ - is incorrect:

```
def generateCirclesRdd(sc: SparkContext,
                       nCircles: Int = 3,
                       nTotalPoints: Int = 30,
                       outerRadius: Double): RDD[(Long, Long, Double)] = {
```

It should apparently be:

```
def generateCirclesRdd(sc: SparkContext,
    nCircles: Int = 3,
    nTotalPoints: Int = 30,
    outerRadius: Double): RDD[(Long, Long, Double)] = {
```

Where is this setting in the IJ code style?  Screenshot shows what I was able to find.

[image]

**UPDATE** There is a comment about "Tabs and Indents" here it is :

[image]

**Another Update**: @yole has provided a helpful answer. However, I am still left with 2 spaces instead of 4 on the continuation.

For reference, here is the correct/required indentation within Spark. Notice the continuation on method declarations is 4 spaces.

```
  def train(
      data: RDD[Vector],
      k: Int,
      maxIterations: Int,
      runs: Int,
      initializationMode: String,
      seed: Long): KMeansModel = {
```

However the continuation on method *invocations* is only two:

```
    new KMeans().setK(k)
      .setMaxIterations(maxIterations)
      .setRuns(runs)
      .setInitializationMode(initializationMode)
      .setSeed(seed)
      .run(data)
```

Comment: I would guess that the option you need is "Use normal indent for parameters".

Comment: Nice idea: unfortunately that change had no effect.

Comment: Chek `Tabs and Indents` tab on the left top corner

Comment: @deathangel908  Updated OP with it - not much here..

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is two option that you have to change

1. Uncheck **Method declaration parameters | Align when multiline**

[image]

2. Check **other | Alternate indentation for constructor args and parameter declarations with 4 spaces**

[image]

Comment: would you pls post a screenshot? i am on a different version of IJ

Comment: This was the right answer for me, 2017.3.3. Thank you!!

Answer (score 37):

Uncheck "Method declaration parameters | Align when multiline" and enable "Use normal indent for parameters".

Comment: This is close:  we need 4 spaces for the indentation and not two. I am updating the OP.

Comment: I gave an upvote to indicate your answer is at least a step in the right direction.

Comment: If you need 4 spaces, then disable "Use normal indent for parameters".

Comment: I don't see a "Use normal indent for parameters" setting in IJ 2017

Comment: Changed correct answer to the next one simply due to versioning changes .

Answer (score 6):

In 2017, Check all the Settings/Editor/CodeStyle/Java/Wrapping and Braces options, where the line name is Allign when multiline. For me, it was checked at Chained Method calls, and that made these long indents. Just uncheck them.

Comment: YES! IntelliJ was driving me insane, been looking to solve this one for quite a while. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

enable "other | Alternate indentation for constructor args and parameter declarations with 4 spaces" help me out finally

Comment: with "Tabs and Indents | 2 2 2"

Comment: by the way ,this is really wired indentaion format.

Answer (score 0):

This is that worked for me:

- Enable "Align when multiline"
- Enable "Use normal indent for parameters"
- All other options "Method declaration parameters" are disabled

[image]